# Sort numbers using function(s) in Excel

Tags: excel

Apart from using the sort function (which is available to only MS 365 subscribers for now), is there a function (or combination of functions) that can be used to return a list of numbers (say 4,5,1,5,3,2,4 in column A) to another column in increasing order?

Answer (score 4):

Use `AGGREGATE`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,4,$A$1:$A$7,ROW())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, although, I used the small function directly.

Comment: Would have been nice to have short explanation of what the aggregate function does, and it's arguments. I.e. What does the `15;4` do?

Comment: @not2qubit ```15``` means function type ```SMALL``` and ```4``` means option ```Ignore nothing```, so ```AGGREGATE``` returns k smallest value from range ```A1:A7```.